# List view comes over the toolbar when I test it on lollipop and higher Api

Tags: xml, listview, xamarin.android, navigationbar

Here is my Layout with list view and Navigation as the list view overlaps and makes the navigation Bar inaccessible.I switched the list view in the layout tried different solutions but was unable to set it right. Here is how it appears when i run it.

[image: List View]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
              android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
              <include
                  layout="@layout/toolbar" />

                </RelativeLayout>
              <ListView
                       android:id="@+id/listview"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:dividerHeight="1px"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                       android:divider="#000000"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                       android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                 />
          </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
          <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

Can anybody help.

Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using RelativeLayout, you can use "layout_below" parameter
the code will be like that :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <include
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          layout="@layout/toolbar" />
      <ListView
               android:id="@+id/listview"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
               android:dividerHeight="1px"
               android:divider="#000000"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It shows an unhandled exception at the toolbar when i debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CoordinatorLayout solved my issue.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/content_frame"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
      <include
          layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvTenant"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
      android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      layout_anchor="@id/lvTenant"`enter code here`
            layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            layout_behavior="helpers.FABCoordinatorBehavior" />
</RelativeLayout>
```